# YUM attempt to install instead of update MySQL packages

Tags: mysql, yum, update

I have a doubt about the difference between install and Upgrade message with YUM Update.

I have 2 servers with MySQL 5.6.25 installed on then "Server A" and "Server B".

When I run the command:

```
YUM update
```

I get in server A the install packages option:

```
Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package                   Arch      Version         Repository            Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 mysql-community-client    x86_64    5.6.28-2.el6    mysql56-community     18 M
     replacing  MySQL-client.x86_64 5.6.25-1.linux_glibc2.5
 mysql-community-devel     x86_64    5.6.28-2.el6    mysql56-community    3.3 M
     replacing  MySQL-devel.x86_64 5.6.25-1.linux_glibc2.5
 mysql-community-libs      x86_64    5.6.28-2.el6    mysql56-community    1.9 M
     replacing  MySQL-shared.x86_64 5.6.25-1.linux_glibc2.5
 mysql-community-server    x86_64    5.6.28-2.el6    mysql56-community     53 M
     replacing  MySQL-server.x86_64 5.6.25-1.linux_glibc2.5
Installing for dependencies:
 mysql-community-common    x86_64    5.6.28-2.el6    mysql56-community    307 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install       5 Package(s)

Total download size: 76 M
Is this ok [y/N]:
```

And in the server B the Upgrade packages option:

```
Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package                      Arch    Version          Repository          Size
================================================================================
Updating:
 mysql-community-server       x86_64  5.6.28-2.el6     mysql56-community   53 M
Updating for dependencies:
 mysql-community-client       x86_64  5.6.28-2.el6     mysql56-community   18 M
 mysql-community-common       x86_64  5.6.28-2.el6     mysql56-community  307 k
 mysql-community-libs         x86_64  5.6.28-2.el6     mysql56-community  1.9 M
 mysql-community-libs-compat  x86_64  5.6.28-2.el6     mysql56-community  1.6 M

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Upgrade       5 Package(s)

Total download size: 75 M
Is this ok [y/N]:
```

what is the difference?

Comment: The packages were renamed.

Comment: Hello, thanks for quick answer, how can I solve the problem? I mean, how can I rename the packages correctly and safely?

Comment: You just press "Y".

Comment: Ok, now i get warning: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: V3 DSA/SHA1 signature: key ID 5072e1f5: NOKEY

Comment: Preferred method would be to mport the key or you can run it with --nogpgcheck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'd need to see the complete yum output to know for sure. Likely Server A and Server B are probably starting with different packages installed. Server A has packages using names that have been replaced with newer names where as Server B has packages that match the current names.

Comment: Hello @ScottDodson as you said, that was the problem, 
apparently package names were changed, thank you for your input!